# Inject Data with Guice into JavaFX ViewController

Tags: java, javafx, guice

Today I added Guice to my Java FX Application. The main goal was to replace the singletons I had with Injection and break up dependencies.
So far everything worked fine, this is the code I have to start a new Scene:

```
public class App extends Application{

public static void main(String[] args){
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    final String LANGUAGE_BUNDLE = "myBundlePath";
    final String FXML = "myFXMLPath";

    try {
        ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(LANGUAGE_BUNDLE, Locale.GERMAN, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(FXML), resourceBundle, new JavaFXBuilderFactory(), getGuiceControllerFactory());
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(fxmlLoader.load()));
        primaryStage.show();
    }catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private Callback<Class<?>, Object> getGuiceControllerFactory(){
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new GuiceModule());
    return new Callback<Class<?>, Object>() {
        @Override
        public Object call(Class<?> clazz) {
            return injector.getInstance(clazz);
        }
    };
}
}
```

My Guice Module looks like this:

```
public class GuiceModule extends AbstractModule {
@Override
protected void configure() {
    bind(ITester.class).to(Tester.class);
    bind(ISecondTest.class).to(SecondTest.class);
}
}
```

Please note that i substituted the paths for the ressource bundle and the fxml file as they would have revealed my identity. But loading and everything works, so this shouldn't be a problem ;)

Now the problem is, that I want to instantiate a new view with a button click in a different view. The second view should display a more detailed version of the data in view 1.
Everything that I need to pass to the second view is an Integer (or int), but I have absolutely no clue on how to do this.

I have the standard FX setup with:

```
View.fxml (with a reference to the ViewController)
ViewController.java
Model.java
ViewModel.java
```

The `ViewController` then binds to properties offered by the `ViewModel`.
I need the int to choose the correct model.

Everything I could find was about the Annotation `@Named` but as far as I can see, this wouldn't be usable to inject dynamic data.

Could you please give me a hint what this what I want to do is called?
Or long story short: How can I inject a variable, chosen by a different view, in a second `ViewController`, and leaving the rest in the standard FX-way?

Any help appreciated and thanks in advance!

Regards, Christian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying around a bit more, it seems like I found a solution by myself!
However, it "feels" ugly what I'm doing, so I'd like to have some confirmation ;)

First the theory: Guice supports "AssistedInject". This is, when a class can not be constructed by a default constructor. In order to be able to use AssistedInject, you have to download the extension (I downloaded the jar from [maven repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.inject.extensions/guice-assistedinject)).

What AssistedInject does for you is that it allows you to specify a factory which builds the variable for you. So here is what I have done:

First, create an interface for the class which you want to use later, in my case:

```
public interface IViewController {
}
```

Second, create an interface for the factory. Important: **you do not have to implement the factory**

```
public interface IControllerFactory {

    ViewController create(@Assisted int myInt);

}
```

Third, add the constructor with the corresponding parameters to your class which you want to instantiate later, **and let it implement the interface you created** like so:

```
public class ViewController implements IViewController{

@AssistedInject
public ViewController(@Assisted int i){
    final String LANGUAGE_BUNDLE = "languageBundle";
    final String FXML = "View.fxml";

    try{
        ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(LANGUAGE_BUNDLE, Locale.GERMAN, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(FXML), resourceBundle, new JavaFXBuilderFactory());
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);
        Stage second = new Stage();
        second.setScene(new Scene(fxmlLoader.load()));
        second.show();
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("ViewController constructor called with: " + i);
}
```

Here are a few things to note:

- The annotation "@AssistedInject" for the method
- The annotation "@Assisted" for the parameter which we want to supply externally
- we set the controller for the loader manually (with fxmlLoader.setController(this);)
- I had to remove the controller configuration in the fxml file, so no "fx:controller" in the fxml!

Next we need to add a variable into the class from where we want to instantiate the other class:

```
@Inject
IControllerFactory controllerFactory;
```

We can use it in the class like so:

```
controllerFactory.create(3)
```

**Note: we call the method "create" which we never implemented in the ViewController class! Guice knows it has to call the constructor - magic**

As last step, we need to add the connection to our context in our GuiceModule, like so:

```
@Override
protected void configure(){
    install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
            .implement(IPagingDirectoryViewController.class, PagingDirectoryViewController.class)
            .build(IPagingDirectoryControllerFactory.class));
}
```

**Note** I got the error: Cannot resolve method 'implement java.lang.Class<"The interface class">, java.lang.Class<"The implementing class">'. This was because I forgot to let my Controller class implement the interface.

Okay, so that's how I got it working.
As I said however, I'd be really happy about some opinions!

Regards, Christian

Answer (score 2):

In your Module Configuration you could simply add a Provider Method for FXMLLoader, in which you assign Guices 'injector.getInstance()' as ControllerFactory for the loader.

```
@Provides
public FXMLLoader getFXMLLoader(com.google.inject.Injector injector) {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();

    loader.setControllerFactory(injector::getInstance);
    return loader;
}
```

All you have to do now, is to bind your ViewControllers in the configure() method of your module configuration.

```
    // for example:
    bind(ViewController.class);
```

And make sure the controller class is properly bound in your fxml file.

```
fx:controller="your.package.ViewController"
```

Now you simply use your injector to get an instance of FXMLLoader.