# Initialising a JavaFX application Screen Management Service using Guice for Dependency Injection

Tags: java, javafx, guice, inject

I have a JavaFX application, and throughout the application the active 'screen' is changed by calling a `loadScene` method on a ScreenService. This ScreenService should be injected as a Singleton via constructor injection (with `@Inject`) into the controllers in which it is needed.

In order to use `@Inject` inside ScreenService to access the injector (necessary for setting an intermediary controllerFactory with `FXMLLoader.setControllerFactory`), I have had to create a new `launch` method that takes in the `primaryStage` and sets it on the object to use later. I hoped this would work because `ScreenService` is marked with `@Inject` inside ServiceModule.java. However, it is initialising `ScreenService` twice currently, and so when a new scene is loaded with `loadScene` there is a `NullPointerException` as `stage` is null.

This would imply that for some reason the `ScreenService` from `injector.getInstance` is a different instance to that being used in, for example, LoginController.java, where `@Inject` is being used to inject `@Screens ScreenService screenService`.

Expected result - when loading a new scene there is no NullPointerException.

I also tried taking some completely different approaches, such as using AssistedInject to inject the primaryStage into the constructor along with the Injector of ScreenService, but that completely failed.

All relevant code snippets:

Main.java:

```java
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new ServiceModule());
        ScreenService screenService = injector.getInstance(ScreenService.class);
        screenService.launch(primaryStage);
    }
```

ServiceModule.java:

```java
public class ServiceModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Qualifier
    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    public @interface Users {}

    @Qualifier
    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    public @interface Assets {}

    @Qualifier
    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    public @interface Screens {}

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Users
    static UserService provideUserService(AssetService assetService) {
        return new UserService(assetService);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Assets
    static AssetService provideAssetService() {
        return new AssetService();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Screens
    static ScreenService provideScreenService(Injector injector) {
        return new ScreenService(injector);
    }
```

ScreenService.java:

```java
public class ScreenService {
    private final HashMap<String, AppScreen> screenMap = new HashMap<>();
    private Stage stage;
    private final Injector injector;

    @Inject
    public ScreenService(Injector injector) {
        System.out.println("init");
        this.injector = injector;
    }


    public void launch(Stage stage) {
        this.stage = stage;
        this.stage.setTitle("Brokerage Application");
        loadScene("/login-view.fxml");
        this.stage.show();
    }

    public void loadScene(String fxmlPath) {
        AppScreen appScreen;
        if (screenMap.containsKey(fxmlPath)) {
            appScreen = screenMap.get(fxmlPath);
        } else {
            appScreen = new AppScreen();
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(fxmlPath));
            loader.setControllerFactory(injector::getInstance);
            try {
                Parent root = loader.load();
                Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 400);
                scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/styles.css").toExternalForm());

                appScreen.setRootController(loader.getController());
                appScreen.setFxmlPath(fxmlPath);
                appScreen.setScene(scene);
                screenMap.put(fxmlPath, appScreen);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (appScreen.getRootController() instanceof RefreshableScreen) {
            ((RefreshableScreen) appScreen.getRootController()).refreshData();
        }
        stage.setScene(appScreen.getScene());

    }
}
```

LoginController.java

```java
    @Inject
    public LoginController(@ServiceModule.Screens ScreenService screenService, @ServiceModule.Users UserService userService) {
        this.screenController = screenService;
        this.userService = userService;
    }
```

Comment: [Gluon ignite](https://gluonhq.com/labs/ignite/) works with Guice.  I haven't tried it, but maybe use that rather than creating your own solution to integrate JavaFX and Guice.  For an overview of mechanisms for injecting into FXML controllers (not Guice specific), see [Eden coding's guide to FXML dependency injection and controller initialisation](https://edencoding.com/dependency-injection/).

Comment: Thanks - currently trying (and struggling) with Gluon Ignite. I think I might have the DI design pattern simply wrong on a deeper level for controlling screens

Comment: Turns out I managed to somehow fix it by leveraging this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36165151/inject-data-with-guice-into-javafx-viewcontroller

I now run `bind()` for all of my controllers, deleted all of the `@Provides` stuff and now just inject with `@Inject` constructor injection and somehow it works.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by taking some advice from [Inject Data with Guice into JavaFX ViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36165151/inject-data-with-guice-into-javafx-viewcontroller)

New ServiceModule.java:

```java
public class ServiceModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        bind(LoginController.class);
        bind(HoldingsController.class);
        bind(RegisterController.class);
        bind(TradeController.class);
    }
}
```

So here all of the controllers for the views are bound, and I removed all of the `@Provides` elements - turns out these are completely unnecessary, and Guice can do the necessary constructor injection without any of that.